# How do I store a changing variable obtained from an iteration, to use it in future iterations?

Tags: matlab, iteration, constants

I am trying to store a variable in an iteration once certain conditions are met. The stored variable will be used in future iterations and reset once the condition is no more met. 
For example:

- I want keep `m(k,i)`constant so that the `i`th iteration of the `k+1`th iteration is the same, ie: `m(k+1,i)= m(k,i)` and `y(k,i)` and `x(k,i)` keep changing accordingly until the `if` condition is NOT met. Then, `m(k,i)` resets and re-initiates the sequence if the condition is met again but using the CURRENT `y(k,i)` and `x(k,i)` to obtain another constant `m(k,i)`.

  ```
   for k=1:200 
      for i=1:49
         if d_p(i)<rp 
              m(k,i)= y(k,i)/x(k,i); %given previous values of x,y
              const = m(k,i);

              u1(i,k)= x(k,i)+cosd(a_s(i,k))/const + sind(a_s(i,k));    %matrix a_s is known.
              u2(i,k)= -4*(y(k,i)+x(k,i)/const) -3*(theta_s(i,k)-90);
         else 
              u1(i,k)=0;
              u2(i,k)=0;
         end
     end
    x(k+1,:)=x(k,:)+u1(:,k).*cosd(a_s(:,k))';
    y(k+1,:)=y(k,:)+u2(:,k).*sind(a_s(:,k))';
  end
  ```

Any help will be extremely appreciated!

Comment: Seems like maybe you should use `m(i)` rather than `m(k,i)`, that way the next iteration on `k` reuses the same vector of `m` (until you change some elements)

Comment: Thanks @BenVoigt. If I use `m(i)`, won't the next iteration reassign a new value to `m(i)` since `y(k,i)` and `x(k,i)` vary at every iteration `k` ?

Comment: if you need m(k,i) instead of m(i), could you put an `(if k > 1) m(k,:) = m(k-1,:)` within the first for loop?

Comment: @Trogdor @BenVoigt just made an edit to the position of `x(k+1,:)` and `y(k+1,:)`. They should be after the inner for loop, apologies.

Comment: @dee: It will only assign a new value if your condition is met.  Otherwise the value from the previous iteration will remain in the vector.

Comment: @BenVoigt: That's exactly the point, I want the new value to be the same as the previous WHEN the condition is met. Usually, every time the condition is met, the next 10 or more iterations also satisfy the condition. Basically, I need the first value of `m` every time the condition is met to be available for the next 10 or more iterations. I hope my goal is clearer now, thanks.

Comment: @dee: Ok, so use `if` to NOT overwrite it, when your condition is met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this meets the exact needs, but here's an attempt.

I introduced two variables, `freeze` and `lastval`. I use freeze to signify using the previous value for `m(k,i)` instead of recalculating it. `lastval` simply stores the most recently calculated value for reuse.

```
freeze = false;
for k=1:200
    for i=1:49
        if d_p(i)<rp
            if not(freeze)
                m(k,i)= y(k,i)/x(k,i); %given previous values of x,y
                freeze = true;  
                lastval = m(k,i);
            else
                m(k,i) = lastval;
            end

            u1(i,k)= x(k,i)+cosd(a_s(i,k))/m(k,i) + sind(a_s(i,k));    %matrix a_s is known.
            u2(i,k)= -4*(y(k,i)+x(k,i)/m(k,i)) -3*(theta_s(i,k)-90);
        else
            freeze = false;
            u1(i,k)=0;
            u2(i,k)=0;
        end
    end
    x(k+1,:)=x(k,:)+u1(:,k).*cosd(a_s(:,k))';
    y(k+1,:)=y(k,:)+u2(:,k).*sind(a_s(:,k))';
end
```

Comment: Note that this carries values over from `m(k,i)` to `m(k,i+1)`, not `m(k+1,i)`.  To fix that, freeze and lastval should be vectors indexed on `i`.